# Wordpress: php code snippets

Tags: php, wordpress

PHP code snippets are not working in Wordpress.

I use the [Shapley theme.](https://colorlib.com/wp/themes/shapely)

Example:

```
<a href="<?php echo get_page_link(40); ?>">Map</a>
```

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_page_link

Comment: where are you using this??

Comment: Are you using in wordpress admin visual editor?

Comment: Question is not clear.Its on the fly I am using